# Why data inside component is not rendered?

Tags: angular

There is a component with input data:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mail-list',
    templateUrl: './mail-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mail-list.component.scss']});

    export class MailListComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() id: number;
        public list: any[] = [];
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
           this.service.load(this.id).subscribe((response) => this.mailist = response)
        }
    }
```

This component is used in another after change variable show `true/false:`

```
<app-mail-list *ngIf="show" [id]="application.id" ></app-mail-list>
```

I dont post template of `MailListComponent` because it is very simple `*ngFor="let m of list"`.

Problem is that when data arrives to `this.mailist = response` it is not rendered in template. Only when user requests data again it is.

How to use that properly, when after activation of component using input parametrs load data inside and show?

Could it be problem cause parent component has:

`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` ?

Comment: You're putting the `response` into a variable named `maillist`, but you only have a variable named `list` in the component. Post all of your code if you want help.

Comment: Sorry it is typo , I have `list` everywhere

Comment: Seems problem is in parent `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove onPush from the parent. But, if you need to render lots of data and performance is an issue, then I would put onPush on the child component instead and use observables for the inputs to the component. That will allow the child to be updated when needed (see #1 below).

To sum it up. With onPush, change detection will only be run and update the view when:

1. an observable emits a new value
2. the input to the Parent changes (has to be a new reference, cannot be just simple object mutation).
3. when a DOM event the component listens to was received
4. when explicitly registering the component to be checked the next change detection turn using ChangeDetectorRef::markForCheck

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps to debug the issue:

1. remove the `*ngIf="show"` to make sure that `show` is not always false and preventing the component from loading.
2. make sure that `this.service.load(this.id)` is actually returning an array with data in it. A `console.log()` in the subscription should be sufficient.
3. make sure your variable names all match. With the TypeScript code provided, the html should look something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let mail of list">
  {{mail}}
</div>
```

4. revert the changeDetection strategy back to it's default value. This shouldn't be the source of the issue, but it won't hurt to make sure.